# Generating a CSR with Security framework on iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, security, frameworks

Anyone know how to generate a CSR from within an iPhone app to send to the CA?

If its not part of the security framework, then how is iPhone suppose to get certificate that authenticate it against a CA?

Thanks much!

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Why would you want to do this (what is the use case)?

Answer (score -2):

I use developer.apple.com to manage these settings to app store/ provisioning profiles.

Comment: The question was asking about how to generate a CSR within an iOS app, not how to manage code signing.